# PHP generated Vcard: Change character encoding so accented character can be displayed

Tags: php, encoding, diacritics, vcf-vcard

I'm using a PHP class to generate vcard: http://www.troywolf.com/articles/php/class_vcard/

But accented character do not show properly. I guess this is related to the character encoding, but I have been unable to find a way to change it.

All my files are saved as UTF8 without BOM and here is what the outpout of the script looks like:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
CLASS:PUBLIC
PRODID:-//www.bla.com//Version 1//EN
REV:2011-08-30 03:19:49
FN:Heïdi DABODFE
N:DABODFE;Heïdi;;;
TITLE:Directrice
ORG:blablabla
ADR;TYPE=work:;;2 Imp. Les Plataness;Mirepoix;;09500;France
EMAIL;TYPE=internet,pref:contact@bla.com
TEL;TYPE=work,voice:05 61 68 64 38
PHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64;TYPE=JPEG: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URL;TYPE=work:www.bla.com
NOTE:bla
TZ:-0500
END:VCARD
```

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try some different programs to import this VCARD? For Version 3.0 they should be fine with utf-8 unless its name starts with "O" and ends with "tlook" ^^

See if this works for you:

```
FN;CHARSET=utf-8:Heïdi DABODFE
N;CHARSET=utf-8:DABODFE;Heïdi;;;
```

Comment: Hello Stephan and thanks for your help... unfortunaly it did not work. I'm using windows contact to read the vcard, do you think another vcard reader would not have the same problem?

Comment: Wich software do you use to read this vcard back in? Try exporting from it to see if there are hints how it likes its VCARDs.

Comment: I'm using "Windows Contact" to read the vcard. I modifed the vcard source to inlude the CHARSET=utf-8 as you advised, but it did not change anything. I would like the vcard to be usable on as many devices as possible. If there are going to be issues with character encoding, it might be better to simply replace accented characters in PHP before to build the vcard? Certainly not the best way, but it seems "safer". What do you think?

Comment: That is cosmetics. It is up to you if you "safecode" the names for all applications or if you stick to the standard and let bad software show bad characters, making all other users happy.

Comment: For now I'll remove all characters that might cause problem. As I'm running out of time and this is much quicker.But when I'll have more time I'll have a closer look at this and see if I can find better a solution. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: There is no standard encoding for Vcard, but the problem seems to be that Outlook (even modern versions) ignores the encoding attribute in the Vcard file. Using ISO-8859-1 everywhere instead made it work for me, [se my answer on another question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671684/character-encoding-issues-with-php-generated-vcards-in-outlook/21516987#21516987)

Comment: Oddly enough the RFC for vCard 4.0 forces you to use UTF8 and does not allow you to change it. I was having problems with this same thing and by trying the "CHARSET=utf-8" advice posted here solved it (in 4.0!). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It would be good if programs would really follow the standards! This is how they should work:

- For [vCard 2.1](http://www.imc.org/pdi/vcard-21.txt), you should use `FN;CHARSET=utf-8;ENCODING=8BIT:Heïdi DABODFE`, because it could also be `ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE` and many programs really do use that. I think Outlook eats this well, however Thunderbird rejects the ENCODING part (Thunderbird also exports supposedly v2.1 vCards without charset/encoding information).
- For [vCard 3.0](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2426.txt) the possibility of using a different charset for each property disappeared (what sense did it made?). You are to use the Content-type MIME header when transferring the vCard and that's where the charset is to be specified (says section 5 of the RFC). However, you don't usually find Content-type headers in vCard files and most programs just use `FN;CHARSET=utf-8;ENCODING=8BIT:Heïdi DABODFE` as it was for 2.1.
- For [vCard 4.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6350) the charset for vCard files is always UTF-8 and there is no way to override this and it is invalid to specify a different charset in a MIME header (section 3.1 of the RFC).

The reality is that most programs treat vCard with very little care and use the same code to handle versions 2.1, 3.0 and 4.*. I generate vCard using UTF-8 to satisfy RFC 6350, use `CHARSET=utf-8` to satisfy vCard 2.1 specification, avoid `ENCODING=8BIT` to satisfy Thunderbird and I'm currently considering adding a MIME header.

It is unfortunate that in 2015 there is still difficulty in dealing with this problem which sounds more like a problem from the 1980s.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is rather something like this,

assuming $vcf to be a string containing utf-8 characters:

```
file_put_contents($dir.$filename, utf8_decode($vcf));
```

French utf-8 characters get displayed properly in Outlook, just found out.