# Character encoding issues with PHP generated vCards in Outlook

Tags: php, character-encoding, vcf-vcard

We're encountering character encoding issues trying to create vcards in PHP.

In Outlook names that use special characters are distorted, like "é" becomes "Ã©".

We updated the header and the FN and N sections for Windows character encoding, but the issue remains.

Grateful for any suggestions.

Vcard excerpt:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
REV:2013-03-27 19:37:46
FN;CHARSET=Windows-1252:Namé S. Nameé
N;CHARSET=Windows-1252:Namé;Namé;;;
TITLE:Associate
ORG:Company
EMAIL;TYPE=internet,pref:name@abc.com
TZ:-0400
END:VCARD
```

PHP Header for Vcard:

```
    header("Content-type: text/x-vcard; charset=windows-1252;");
    header("Content-Length: ".strlen($vc->card));
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$vcard_name.".vcf");
    header("Pragma: public");
```

Comment: Go to the encoding option in your editor and change it from utf8 to windows-1252 then save the file.

Comment: The PHP script generates the vcard file dynamically so any solution would have to fix the issue before it was opened in Outlook.

Comment: Open up your php file go to the encoding option in your editor and change it from utf8 to windows-1252 then save the file.

Comment: @Musa Thanks, but I don't think you're following what we want...we're trying to generate multiple vcards with a PHP script and we already specified that encoding in the header. Re-saving one card locally doesn't address the problem because we need the cards to open correctly to begin with.

Comment: Setting the content type will not change `utf-8` to `windows-1252`, you'll have to convert it whether with an editor or with php (e.g. iconv)

Answer (score 4):

Your solution didn't work for me, I still got funny characters on Windows.

What worked for me was using ISO-8859-1 instead. You can convert UTF8 to ISO-8859-1 in PHP using [utf8-decode()](https://www.php.net/utf8_decode) , and by using `ENCODING=iso-8859-1` in the Vcard for the relevant fields makes it work on most UTF-8 based clients I have tested on.

Header:

```
Content-Type: text/x-vcard; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Vcard example:

```
N;CHARSET=iso-8859-1:Göteborg
```

Tested on Windows, OS X, IOS and Android.

Comment: this solution also worked for me, tested on iOS 13.4.1 and macOS 10.14.6

Answer (score 3):

There were some similar questions, but nothing seemed definitive on this. By specifying the charset in the vcard fields it looks like I was half way there.

I finally got it working by changing the following to "utf-8;":

```
 header("Content-type: text/x-vcard; charset=CHARSET=utf-8;");
```

The same goes for the name fields in the vcard itself. Specifying utf-8 seems to have resolved the display issues of the special characters:

```
$this->card .= "FN;CHARSET=utf-8:".$new_display_name.$this->data['short_mode'];
    $this->card .= "N;CHARSET=utf-8:"
```

Opened in Outlook 2007 with all the accent characters  displaying as intended.